# iOS: How to track firebase dynamic link

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

i have added UTM parameter using FIRDynamicLinkGoogleAnalyticsParameters

```
FIRDynamicLinkGoogleAnalyticsParameters *analyticsParams =
  [FIRDynamicLinkGoogleAnalyticsParameters parametersWithSource:Source
                                                         medium:Medium
                                                       campaign:Campaign];
  analyticsParams.term = Term;
  analyticsParams.content = Content;
  components.analyticsParameters = analyticsParams;
```

Now i want to track the dynamic link like this,

if i have shared on Facebook, any one tap on that link then it will go to application if there else it will go to App Store.

After i need to show message based upon it’s source i.e welcome from Facebook like message.

So can we track dynamic link and check from where the link has been tapped and show relevant message based upon i’t source.

Can anyone explain how to implement this: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics

> By adding these tracking parameters to your Dynamic Links, Google
>   Analytics and iTunes Connect can treat them like any other campaign
>   it's measuring attribution reporting for, and you can view conversion
>   events not just by the ad campaigns responsible for bringing in those
>   users, but also by which Dynamic Links might have brought them in.
>
> The following parameters are passed to Google Analytics: utm_source,
>   utm_medium, utm_campaign, utm_term, utm_content, gclid
>
> The following parameters are passed to the App Store: at, ct, mt, pt

The same question was asked in this thread:

[App link tracking with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716497/app-link-tracking-with-firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also I had posted this question on Firebase GitHub and got the reply:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4775

> You can't track where the link was tapped from unless you create a
>   custom link (or add custom parameters) for each source, but even then
>   this will result in mismatches if a user ever copies a link and shares
>   it to a different source.

Comment: Custom link creation can solve this for you. like for facebook you create a DL specific to facebook etc.